# useTranslation not working in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I have a project write with react/typescript and I want to change language. I use i18n but when i use useTranslation to change language it doesn't work.

packages:

```
"i18next": "22.4.9",
"react-i18next": "12.1.4"
```

i18n -> config.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      translations: require('./locales/en/translations.json')
    }
  },
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations'
});

i18n.languages = ['en'];

export default i18n;
```

i18n -> locales -> en -> translations.json

```
{    
    "errorMessage": "Please try again later."
}
```

App.tsx

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const App = () => {

    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (<>
        {t('errorMessage')}
    </>)
}

export default App
```

On running, I see this:

> errorMessage

instead of

> Please try again later.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the config.js file preferably in ***App.tsx*** file since it has to be bundled.

```
import './i18n/config';
```